# There is any way to transfer a child linux process to another process?

Tags: linux, session, process, terminal, zsh

If i have an zsh terminal with a child process in it, there is any way to transfer this process to another zsh session?

Example: I have a tmux session with two panels, two zsh process and a htop process on the first session, there is some way to pass this process to the second zsh session?

This image can illustrate the situation:

[image]

I've tried `ctrl+z` to send the process to background and `fg %1` on other session but this doesn't work, apparently because the background processing is managed by the zsh session I think...

**There is some way to transfer one child process to another process?**

Comment: It is possible to transfer to another parent. But not a designated parent. The `disown` builtin removes a job from the zsh process table, and when the zsh process terminates, the job is transferred to PID 1 (that is, `init` on Linux, `launchd` on OS X, etc.).

Comment: I had read about `nohup`, it is similar to disown isn't it?

Comment: @4ae1e1 can you turn your comment in an answer? i'll be glad to mark it as correct answer to this question :)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and

Comment: Also, what I wrote was really a comment. It doesn't answer the question (although I'd say the answer is no).

Comment: ok, thanks for the article :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible in common case: child process belong to parent. But you can use `screen` or something like this to share commands output between sessions.